# Getting a syntax error mysql_feth_array

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I am getting a syntax error on this line of code

```html
($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )){  echo"<img src= images/ ".$info['photo'] ." <br>";
```

and i have no idea why? any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Which exact error message do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
if ($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {  
    echo"<img src= 'images/ ".$info['photo'] ."'> <br>";
}
```

You have missed

1) Closing Image tag

2) Need to put the image url in quotes.